# Is it possible to activate AMD emulation on an M1 Mac when deploying to Kubernetes, as is for Docker?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, arm, apple-m1, x86-emulation

As a Docker and Kubernetes newbie, and I'm trying to deploy a Deployment .yaml file to local Kubernetes (Docker Desktop) using `kubectl apply`

This .yaml file works well on any x86_64 computer (tested both on Linux and Intel chip Macs), but fails to work on my M1 Mac, so I tried troubleshooting the image by creating a container first, which works fine (but I noticed the AMD64 Emulation tag in the container name).

The image basically set up a Node server for some api calls. The pod fails at the point of starting the server, the AMD64 emulated container does not, which leads me to think that either there is no AMD64 emulation for Kubernetes yet or it's not activated or properly set.

I'm using Docker Desktop 4.22.0, with 'Use Virtualization framework' and 'Use Rosetta for x86/amd64 emulation on Apple Silicon' options on.

Comment: Use buildx tool from docker to build multiple arch images.  https://www.docker.com/blog/multi-arch-build-and-images-the-simple-way/

Comment: Things usually work out a little better when you post the actual information you have: the yaml to deploy, the dockerfile for the image, if you have it, how you pull, how you build and actual error logs you get.